# Microsoft Excel: Wrong interpretation for number with CSV in a cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv

I have a CSV file with some CSV value in a cell as below.

> 2048,4,0,0,4,"1334,1335,1338,1339"

When I open it with Excel, it shows [image].

How can I let the Excel display the number as `1334,1335,1338,1339`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, you are always better off **Importing** CSV files and not **Opening** them.

You will then have the opportunity to designate that column as `TEXT`.

If you do that, the data will import and display as you specify.

Comment: Just to make the solution more details. Import the data by clicking "From Text/CSV" under "Data" tab. Click "Transform Data", right click on the column header, "Change Type" to "Text".

Comment: @SamTew I did not include it because, although CSV Importation has been around since at least Excel 2003, and possibly earlier, the exact methodology of where to access that feature is version dependent.  Your method would only work in Excel 2010+ with Power Query installed (which was an option in 2010-2013. Earlier versions had different ways of getting to a text-import-wizard.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your Excel has comma as "thousands separator" and period (.) as decimal point. It is in the "Advanced" part of Settings for Excel. If so, one solution might be to change this, another might be to create the CSV file using semicolon as separator (not comma).

Comment: I have tried to untick the "Use system separator" which includes decimal and thousands separator but the problem still exists.